# Add up every 5 rows in a column of integers BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a parser, and have to so some fancy stuff. I am trying not to use python, but I might have to at this point.

Given an STDOUT that looks like this:

```
1
0
2
3
0
0
1
0
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
2
.
.
.
```

For about 100,000 lines. What I need to do is add up every 5, like so:

```
1 - start
0 |
2 | - 6 
3 |
0 - end
0 - start
1 |
0 | - 3
0 |
2 - end
0 - start
3 |
0 | - 7
4 |
0 - end
5 
0 
2 
. 
.
.
```

The `-`, `|`, `start`, `end`, are all for visual representation, I just need it in a column list:

```
 6
 3
 7
 .
 .
 .
```

I currently have a method of doing this by using an increment `head -n $i` and `tail -n 5` to cut 5 rows out of the list, then I use `paste -sd+ - | bc` to add up all the values. But this is wayyyy to slow because there is 100,000 columns.

If anyone has anything to add I would appreciate it. Let me know if more info is needed.

Thank you

Comment: `perl -lne  '$t+=$_;if(not$.%5){print $t;$t=0;}' file`

Comment: golf, eh @k-five? `awk '0*(t+=$1)==NR%5{print t;t=0}' file` is 18 char shorter :-)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `awk` is a natural tool to use:

```
awk '{ sum += $1 } NR % 5 == 0 { print sum; sum = 0 }'
```

Add values in column 1 to `sum`.  If the record number modulo 5 is 0, print the sum and reset it to 0.  Note that if the last group of records is short (1-4 elements in the group), their sum is not printed.  If you want the sum for the short group printed, add `END { if (NR % 5 != 0) print sum }` to the script.

Since this makes a single pass over the data file using a single command, it will be hard to beat it.  Using Perl might be a little faster.  I don't know how Python would fare against either Awk or Perl.

Comment: Took a whopping 0.055s for 100k lines.

Comment: @Jack: It's unlikely to be relevant whether you can beat that with an alternative language.  I think you may have benefited from most of the file already being in the kernel's file buffer cache.  But it's good to have any timing figure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk for it.
Say file named `file1` contains

```
1
0
2
3
0
0
1
0
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
.
.
.
```

So the awk command goes like:

```
awk 'begin{sum=0;} {sum=sum+1;if(NR%5==0){print sum;sum=0;}}' file1
```

Comment: In Awk, variables are automatically initialized to 0 (or an empty string), so the `begin` block (which is normally spelled `BEGIN` in upper case) isn't really needed.  In the per line code, you add `1` rather than `$1` to the sum — you're counting rows, not summing the values in those rows.  The output from your sample data (ignoring the three lines with dots on them) is three lines saying `5`.